# Best way to write same code for both (web and API) with different type of response?

Tags: laravel

I am working on a laravel project where I have to write code for web-app as well as APIs with same business logic.

Since there is no difference in business logic so I am thinking to write code in traits and use them in different controllers and send response according to request headers. In this way same code will serve both web-app and mobile apps.

Using traits I can write different routes and make different controllers for web and APIs easily.

For example

```
In web.php
Route::get('users','UsersController@index');
In api.php
Route::get('users','Api\UsersController@index');
```

And then using trait I can write only one function called index or any other name like shown below.
For now I check if request wants JSON using `wantsJson()` method of `Request` class.

```
public function index(Request $request){
     $users = User::all();

    if($request->wantsJson()){
       return response()->json(['users',$users]); 
    }
    return view('uses.index',compact('users'));
}
```

Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Create a service and put your common code in there and use it.

Comment: What about repository pattern ? Is that also good for this requirement ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a service and put your common code in there and use it.

On your Laravel application, just go into `app/Services`, then create a class: `[Something]Service`. Add a `[Some]()` method and paste your code to create the new entity

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
     $users = User::all();

    if($request->wantsJson()){
       $users = response()->json(['users',$users]); 
    }
    return $users;
}
```

Now, you can edit your UsersController and inject your service through your constructor, so you can use it as a property.

Finally, your controller method should look like this:

```
public function webControllerFunction(Request $request)
{
    $users = $this->[Something]Service->index($request);

    return view('uses.index',compact('users'));
}

public function apiControllerFunction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->[Something]Service->index($request);
}
```